# Filtering a nested array based on 2 or more values in specific indices

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, indices

I have a simple nested array that looks like this:

```
var test_array = [["0", "0.1", "4.2", "Kramer Street"], ["1", "0.2", "3.5", "Lamar Avenue"], ["3", "4.2", "7.1", "Kramer Street"]];
```

Each subarray has and index of 0 - 3. Suppose I want a function to get the value of index 2 where index 1 = "4.2" and index 3 = "Kramer Street". I know I could use something like the below to return the subarray that match ["4.2", "Kramer Street"], but in my problem, this is tricky because technically, it returns 2 subarrays where I only want one that matches based on the specified indices:

```js
var test_array = [
  ["0", "0.1", "4.2", "Kramer Street"],
  ["1", "0.2", "3.5", "Lamar Avenue"],
  ["3", "4.2", "7.1", "Kramer Street"]
];

function matcher(array1, array2) {
  return array1.every(value => array2.includes(value));
}

function array_parser(array, keywords) {
  return array.filter(values => matcher(keywords, values));
}

var new_array = array_parser(test_array, ["4.2", "Kramer Street"]);

console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to **filter** an Array where **indexes and values** matches, pass an Object as the second argument, where the property is the unique index and the value is the string to match.
Since array indexes are unique-per-se  an object is the best fit since its properties must also be unique.

Than use a combination of: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and finally match by [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) pairs:

```js
/**
 * Filter Array of sub-Arrays where "indexes have value"
 * @param {Array} arr Array to filter
 * @param {Object} ob Object with index/value pairs
 * @return {Array} A filtered array of subarrays.
 */
const filterByIndexValue = (arr, ob) =>
  arr.filter(sub => Object.entries(ob).every(([i, v]) => sub[i] === v));


// DEMO TIME:
const test_array = [
  ["0",  "0.1", "4.2",  "Kramer Street"],
  ["3",  "4.2", "7.1",  "Kramer Street"],  // << get this one
  ["6",  "0.2", "3.5",  "Lamar Avenue"],
  ["99", "4.2", "99.1", "Kramer Street"],  // << get this one
];

// Filter test_array where sub-arrays
// index 1 has value "4.2" and
// index 3 has value "Kramer Street"

const new_array = filterByIndexValue(test_array, {
  1: "4.2",
  3: "Kramer Street"
});
console.log(new_array);
```

Comment: This works well. Using the index values as keys was a smart idea. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Glad it was helpful @gwydion93

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.find`

```js
var test_array = [
  ["0", "0.1", "4.2", "Kramer Street"],
  ["1", "0.2", "3.5", "Lamar Avenue"],
  ["3", "4.2", "7.1", "Kramer Street"]
];

test_array.find(arr => arr[1] === "4.2" && arr[3] === "Kramer Street")[2]
```